# Size of Opencv DNN Net 1x1

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I have implemented a neural network in Tensorflow to segment images. The network is quite simple and only uses Cov2D, MaxPooling and UpSampling2D.

The specs are:

- Tensorflow: 1.14.0
- Keras: 2.2.4-tf
- Ubuntu: 18.04.4 LTS

Once the network was trained I have converted it to .pb, to be able to read it from OpenCV and C++ on Windows PC.

- Windws 10
- Opencv: 4.2.0

The C++ code I am using is:

```cpp
cv::Mat imgOriginal = cv::imread(pathOriginal, 1);//1280x1024 image to segment.

#include <opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp>
cv::dnn::Net MODEL = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("model.pb");//Load model.
MODEL.setInput(cv::dnn::blobFromImage(imgOriginal, 1/255., cv::Size(64, 64)));//Pass image to Net.
cv::Mat m = MODEL.forward();
cout << m.size();

Print Output: [1x1]
```

I don't understand why the output is this size [1x1]. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

An intermediate step is needed after the .forward(). Something of the style would remain:

```cpp
m = MODEL.forward();
cv::Mat detectionMat(m.size[2], m.size[3], CV_32FC1, m.ptr());
```

Now detectionMat has the correctly dimensions of output.